# Need GStreamer command for streaming video

Tags: streaming, gstreamer

can any one give me working (GStreamer) command for streaming video over udp

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example using test audio and video source

```
gst-launch audiotestsrc ! ffenc_mp2 ! mpegtsmux name=mux ! udpsink host=239.1.1.1 auto-multicast=true port=1234 videotestsrc ! ffenc_mpeg2video bitrate=200000 ! mux.
```

You can play this in vlc using this url:

```
udp://@239.1.1.1:1234
```

If you do not want multicast, but unicast instead, enter the ip address at the udpsink options, for example `host=192.168.1.1`. The vlc url then becomes `udp://@:1234`.